# how to center form fields in the sidebar

Tags: forms, center

[enter link description here](http://hallmusicstudio.phinhall.net/)

this is the site in question, I want to center the contact form and the submit button on the side bar, this site is using WordPress. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields are inside of `<p>` tags and are `inline` so you can align them like text.

Either add the following at the end of your style sheet, or add the attributes to the existing selectors in your style sheet.

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap, .widget-area .widget p {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpcf7-form {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```